# Model for small sample time series

Tags: time-series, regression, dataset, arima

Im a total novice and i need to estimate some kind of relation-proof model(Granger test results, correl matrix are already provide some evidence) with following dataset:
20 observations (2001-2021), 4 variables, one dependent. Some of them are non-stationary, which method should i use and why (ARIMA, VAR, VECM, BVAR etc)?

Comment: Can you provide a few more details? F.e. what is your target variable (dependent variable), what are your features (or exogeneous variable) and what is a relation-proof model? In general all your variables need to be stationary, which could be achieved by differencing. What